# Creating PDF with JavaScript Supporting Right To Left

Tags: javascript, pdf-generation

I am a beginner to JavaScript and I know there are ways to create PDF file on the fly. One of the examples I found is jsPDF (hspdf.com)

How ever, and as far as I understand, jsPDF does not support right to left langauges (such as Arabic or Hebrew). Do yuu know any way to create PDF file on the fly with RTL support ?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: FIX: Sorry... its jsPDF and not hspdf !! Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have another option for you, that is **[TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org)**.

TCPDF is a PDF creator to work with PHP, and not JavaScript. But you may link PHP and JavaScript using AJAX. An easy method will be to use **[jQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)**. You may pass the data using JavaScript to PHP through AJAX to process the data to create PDF. TCPDF is completely compatible with HTML and CSS. You may design the layout using HTML. For the text you want to print from right to left, simply use CSS property;

```
.element_class{
  direction:rtl;
}
```

**[Here](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php)** are some examples of TCPDF.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. After creating the PDF, how to you pop the "Save/Open" window to the user ?